# iOS - Error connecting to db on real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have been working on an Ionic Phonegap project for iOS. There is a method implemented in `Appdelegate.m` which makes an AJAX request to download a text file from a server, which contains a URL to connect to another server in order for the app to work.

I have made two classes,
`WebContent` and `WebCustomContent`

In `WebContent.m` I insert a particular URL taken from the text file to a sqlite DB and then retrieve it using `WebCustomContent.m`

Refer to the following code block

```
-(NSString*)getDataBasePath{

    //CHECK
    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"webcontentdb.sqlite"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];
    NSLog(@"%d", fileExists);


    //END OF CHECK



    //SIMULATOR
    NSString *databasePath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"webcontentdb" ofType:@"sqlite"];
   // return databasePath1;


    //REAL DEVICE
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"webcontentdb.sqlite"];
    return databasePath;
}


-(void)updateUserAgeRange:(NSString*)age{

    NSString* databasePath = [self getDataBasePath];
    sqlite3 *database;


    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update  user_setting set valstr =   '%@'  where keystr = 'AGE' ", age];

        NSLog(@"update %@" , query);

        const char * sql = [query UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_step(compiledStatement); // Here is the added step.
            NSLog(@"updateContact SUCCESS - executed command %@",query);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"updateContact FAILED - failed to execute command %@",query);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    else {
        //NSLog(@"pdateContact FAILED - failed to open database");
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);

}


- (NSString *)getUserPreferenceValues:(NSString*)keystr {



    NSString *retval = [[NSString alloc] init] ;
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT valstr  FROM user_setting where keystr = '%@'  " , keystr];

    NSLog(@" query  %@", query);


    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


            char *nameChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0 );

            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:nameChars];

            NSLog(@" valstr  %@", name);
            retval = name;


        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }


    return retval;
}

-(void)insertDatabaseCommonValues:(NSString*)urlstr{

    NSString* databasePath = [self getDataBasePath];


    sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from  url_preference"];


        const char * sql = [query UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_step(compiledStatement); // Here is the added step.
            // NSLog(@"updateContact SUCCESS - executed command %@",query);
        }
        else {
            //NSLog(@"updateContact FAILED - failed to execute command %@",query);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    else {
        //NSLog(@"pdateContact FAILED - failed to open database");
    }




    //************************************INSERT************************************//

    //sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {


        //NSLog(@"URL STRING %@",urlstr);

        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into url_preference (name) values (  '%@'  ) ", urlstr];

        NSLog(@"inset %@" , query);

        const char * sql = [query UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        NSLog(@" error code.. %d",sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL));

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_step(compiledStatement); // Here is the added step.
            NSLog(@"updateContact SUCCESS - executed command %@",query);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"updateContact FAILED - failed to execute command %@",query);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    else {
        //NSLog(@"pdateContact FAILED - failed to open database");
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

Here, when I print the BOOL variable fileExists, it prints YES, meaning the database exists in Documents folder.
But insertion and update queries fail as follows;

```
2015-06-22 11:18:18.215 App Name[5510:60b] URL http://www.google.lk
2015-06-22 11:18:22.082 App Name[5510:60b] 1
2015-06-22 11:18:24.103 App Name[5510:60b] success to open database!
2015-06-22 11:18:26.197 App Name[5510:60b] 1
2015-06-22 11:18:28.673 App Name[5510:60b] inset insert into url_preference (name) values (  'http://www.google.lk'  ) 
2015-06-22 11:18:28.676 App Name[5510:60b]  error code.. 1
2015-06-22 11:18:28.679 App Name[5510:60b] updateContact FAILED - failed to execute command insert into url_preference (name) values (  'http://www.google.lk'  )
```

I've placed the database file in the project folder as shown below;

[image]

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible this is a file permissions problem?  I would suggest right-clicking the `webcontentdb.sqlite` file in Finder, select `Get Info`, and under Sharing & Permissions make all users have `Read & Write` privileges.

If that doesn't work, I would use an SQLite browser app to verify that the database file can be written to and is not corrupted in any way.